# Migration problem with "Notes & Attachment" in Salesforce

Tags: notes

I have created a new SF org & successfully moved all data EXCEPT notes & attachment. From the previous org, I have Attachments folder & Attachment.csv file exported.

When I am trying to upload attachment by **jitterbit**, it is throwing the following error. 
[image: jitterbit]

In the exported Attachment.csv file (from previous org), BODY column is missing which is required in INSERT/UPSERT attachment operation for the new org. 
I am trying to migrate all Notes & Attachments from previous org to new org. 
The below screenshot is for a particular record (I need related Attachments for all records).

When I am trying to export only the Attachments using **Data Loader**  from old org, but Java heap size error & export fails. The total size of the Attachment folder is about 158MB. Both old & current org are Salesforce Production org.

[image: Note & Attachment]

Answer (score 0):

You can always migrate the Notes and Attachment data (and all other objects too) via API. At Import2, we offer Notes and Attachments migration by default in our data migrations. If you’d like to give it a try, you can set up a free sample here: https://www.import2.com/salesforce/from/salesforce

*I manage the customer experience for data migrations with Import2*

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your existing CRM (Salesforce Editions), the Data2CRM migration service can help you migrate the notes and attachments to your new Salesforce CRM automatically or with the help of Service Packages. In case you are interested, you may stop by and perform a trial run at https://www.data2crm.com/migration/crm/salesforce-migration-service/

I work as the marketing manager at Data2CRM.